# How to add JSON array to Sqlite Database in Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, sqlite, adapter

I have a JSON array call from the network and passed as an arraylist that was set to a recyclerview adapter the first hierarchy call has a size of 4 elements which i wan to save those elements to an sqlite database wit just one column. the JSON call is as below.

```
private void loadJSON(){

    Service serviceAPI = Client.getClient();
    Call<JsonArray> loadRecipeCall = serviceAPI.readRecipeArray();

    loadRecipeCall.enqueue(new Callback<JsonArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonArray> call, Response<JsonArray> response) {

            try {

                String recipeString = response.body().toString();
                Log.i("onResponse", recipeString);
                Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Recipe>>() {}.getType();
                recipeList = new Gson().fromJson(recipeString, listType);
                Log.i("onResponse", recipeList.toString());

                recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecipeAdapter(getApplicationContext(), recipeList));
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonArray> call, Throwable t) {

            Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());

        }


    });
}
```

How can i save the "List recipeList" to SQlite Database basically i need the insertFunction structure that would carry that out. A database of just one column for recipe name which are, Nuttella Pie, Brownies .... just four names which the recipeList contain.

Answer (score 0):

To create a db, and to add or get any info you need to create a class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper. I wrote a sample class according to your need:

```
public class UserDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String column1 = "ID";
private static String column2 = "recipe";
private static String tableName = "Recipes";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TESTINFO.DB";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String CREATE_QUERY =
        "CREATE TABLE "+tableName+" ( " + column1 + " INTEGER primary key, " + column2 + " TEXT unique);";


public UserDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    Log.e("Database operations", "Database created or opened...");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
    Log.e("Database operations", "Database created...");
}

public void addInformation( String recipe, SQLiteDatabase db) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(column2, recipe);
    db.insertWithOnConflict(tableName, null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE)
    Log.e("Database operations", "One row inserted ...");
}

public Cursor getInformations(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Cursor cursor;
    String[] projections = {column1,column2};
    cursor = db.query(
            tableName,
            projections,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );

    return cursor;
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
}
```

In activity, to insert data you need to add some lines to your activity:

```
 private void loadJSON(){

    Service serviceAPI = Client.getClient();
    Call<JsonArray> loadRecipeCall = serviceAPI.readRecipeArray();

    loadRecipeCall.enqueue(new Callback<JsonArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonArray> call, Response<JsonArray> response) {

            try {

                String recipeString = response.body().toString();
                Log.i("onResponse", recipeString);
                Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Recipe>>() {}.getType();
                recipeList = new Gson().fromJson(recipeString, listType);
                Log.i("onResponse", recipeList.toString());

                recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecipeAdapter(getApplicationContext(), recipeList));
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                          UserDBHelper userDBHelper = new UserDBHelper(MainActivity.this);
                          SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = userDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                          foreach(String recipe : recipeList)
                          userDBHelper.addInformation(recipe, sqLiteDatabase);
                          userDBHelper.close();
                        }
                    });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonArray> call, Throwable t) {

            Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());

        }


    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me and worked with little modification. But on launch of the MainActivity any other time recipe data kept adding up to the sqlite database, How can I stop that action for multiple data adding to database on relaunch of the activity

Comment: You will need to `insertWithOnConflict` method... I will edit my answer and fix that code. Please, upvote and accept the post as an answer if it helped you

Comment: I changed the answer a bit. (See the 'edited'). Make sure that you have unistall and install the app before running this code. This is because, you need to delete the database before changing it.
Alternatively you can run `getApplicationContext().deleteDatabase("TESTINFO.DB")`. But first way would be much easier

Comment: Yes this worked  db.insertWithOnConflict(Contract.TABLE_NAME, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE)